# Synchronous and Asynchronous client code in Scala

Tags: multithreading, scala, rest

This is a follow-up to my old [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25360472/synchronous-http-call-in-scala). Suppose I need to invoke a REST service *both* synchronously and asynchronously. In the synchronous case I would like to do it on the caller thread without taking other threads from the pool.

I would like to write my business logic only *once* and reuse it in the both cases. The business logic consists of building a request and handling the response.

I would like also to *compose* REST invocations, as if in "invoke service A and then service B and then service C"

How would you do it in Scala ?

Comment: Do you want to achieve it via Akka or using the Java concurrency facilities? Also have you considered Play?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6581188/is-there-an-executorservice-that-uses-the-current-thread might give some insight. Then you could pass the "current-thread" executor for the sync case and a real executor with other threads for the async.

Comment: @I.K. I would prefer Scala to Java. Akka and Play are probably Ok.

Comment: @RichHenry  Yes, I can use `Executor`, `Runnable`, and `Callable` but I am afraid that the resulting code will look so ugly that it does not worth it.

Comment: Well I thought you would feed that to `ExecutionContext.fromExecutorService` instead of using the global context, and still use `Future` etc. I wasn't suggesting to use the Java types directly.

Comment: Remember you can control the implicit execution context used by Future and the rest of the Scala APIs, and via this mechanism you can control how threads are created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should run in the current thread...

```
{
  val currentThreadEx = new AbstractExecutorService {
    override def execute(r: Runnable) { r.run }
    override def shutdownNow(): java.util.List[Runnable] = new java.util.ArrayList[Runnable]()
    override def shutdown() {}
    override def isTerminated = false
    override def isShutdown = false
    override def awaitTermination(timeout: Long, unit: TimeUnit) = false
  }
  implicit val exContext = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(currentThreadEx)

  val f = Future {
    10 + 1
  } 

  println(Await.result(f, 1 seconds))
}
```

This will run on the default executor...

```
{
  import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

  val f = Future {
    10 + 1
  } 

  println(Await.result(f, 1 seconds))
}
```

As you can see, you can use ExecutorService as the abstraction point.

Or you can use a function written in terms of Monads, and then you can bind those operations together without dealing with the context (i.e. Future).

```
  def op1[M[_]: Monad](i: Int)(j: Int): M[Int] = {
    Monad[M].point { i * j }
  }

  println(Monad[Id].point(10) >>= op1[Id](10))
  println((Future { 10 } >>= op1[Future](10)).run)
```

Comment: Thanks. So you are suggesting implement the business logic as a `Future` and use different `Executors` for sync and async cases. Since `Futures` are composable I can probably compose invocations of different services implemented as `Futures`. Is it correct ?

Comment: This is one way to do it. And you can compose futures. Scalaz monads could also help switching between Id and Future as the monadic type but I thought that would be to complicated a solution given what you asked.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how `scalaz` monads may help ? I know `scalaz` a bit and know what monads are.

Comment: Ill post a simple example above, basically you write your operations in terms of monads and then you can switch which type you use.